# How to search a single node, not all nodes

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I'm using XPath selectors to select each item on a page (roughly 24) and then I'm using XPath selectors on each item to return values from each one.

Even though I'm running the XPath selectors on the subnode it seems to be searching across all subnodes where I only want it done over each subnode individually.

Here's the code that searches for each item on the `doc` and then iterates each `html_listing`. It then passes it to a `get_field_data_from`:

```
def get_listing(doc,field_data = {})
  doc.xpath(get_listing_tag[:path]).each do |html_listing|
    fd = get_field_data_from(html_listing,field_data)
    if !field_data &&  fd.detect {|_,data| !data }
      set_uri doc.xpath(get_sub_page_tag[:path])
      get
      fd = get_listing(Nokogiri::HTML(body),fd)
    end
    yield fd
  end
end
```

So it iterates over all the `Fields` I'm looking for which is used to retrieve the XPath selector containing strings using

```
selector = send("get_%s_tag" % field)
```

If the selector exists and the data has not already been found it will use the XPath selector on the HTML `item`, store the text using

```
res[field] = item.xpath(selector[:path]).inner_text
```

and then return the resulting hash to be used in the next iteration.

```
def get_field_data_from(item,data)
  Fields.inject(data) do |res,field|
    selector = send("get_%s_tag" % field)
    unless !selector || res[field]
      begin
        res[field] = item.xpath(selector[:path]).inner_text
      rescue Exception => e
        puts "Error for field: %s" % field
        raise e
      end
    end
    res
  end
end
```

Somehow it seems that doing

```
res[field] = item.xpath(selector[:path]).inner_text
```

it seems to search over all the items rather then just that given item listing. I know it's doing that because:

1. doing:

   ```
   puts item.xpath(selector[:path]).inner_text
   ```

   Returns more than one result
2. I'm not actually looping over all the html_listings. Where it yields the field data `yield fd` in `get_listing` I do a `break` so it only does it once.

I can't seem to figure out what's going on. Does someone else see it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to anchor the XPath queries on the elements:

- `node.xpath("//example")` does a global search
- `node.xpath(".//example")` does a local search starting at the current node

Notice the leading dot `.` which anchors the query at the current node. Otherwise the query is run against the root node, even if you call it from the current node.

If you are searching by tag name consider using CSS selectors instead. They have fewer pitfalls than XPath. CSS always searches from the current node.

Comment: Alas yes, xpath is confusing like that.

Comment: wtf? What's the point of doing xpath on a subnode if it's still going to run it against all the subnodes siblings? That makes no sense, any way, thanks that worked, will tick answer when stack lets me.

Answer (score 1):

There's another, equally serious, problem.

```
item.xpath(selector[:path]).inner_text
```

`xpath` returns a NodeSet. `inner_text` will concatenate the result of all nodes in the NodeSet, resulting in a string that usually won't be what you want.

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<html>
  <body>
    <p>foo</p>
    <p>bar</p>
  </body>
</html>
EOT

doc.search('p').class # => Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet
doc.search('p').inner_text # => "foobar"
```

Instead you need to use `map` to walk the list of nodes, then get the text:

```
doc.search('p').map(&:inner_text) # => ["foo", "bar"]
```

or, for simplicity:

```
doc.search('p').map(&:text) # => ["foo", "bar"]
```

See "[How to avoid joining all text from Nodes when scraping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43594656/how-to-avoid-joining-all-text-from-nodes-when-scraping)" also.